# MySQL - Select all geometries inside a rectangle

Tags: mysql, sql, geospatial

I have a table AREAGEOMETRY with the following structure:

```
+-----------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field           | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| AREAGEOMETRY_ID | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| AreaManagerId   | int(11)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| AreaId          | text     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| EndDateArea     | datetime | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| StartDateArea   | datetime | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| AreaGeometryTxt | text     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

It contains data from parking zones. Now what I am trying to do is selecting all rows within a bounding box.

A bounding box may be the following:

```
LatLngBounds{southwest=lat/lng: (52.35631327204287,4.881156384944916), northeast=lat/lng: (52.38006384519922,4.913054890930653)}
```

I came up with the following query for this:

```
SELECT * FROM AREAGEOMETRY WHERE ST_OVERLAPS(GeomFromText(AreaGeometryTxt), GeomFromText('LINESTRING(52.35631327204287 4.881156384944916, 52.38006384519922 4.881156384944916, 52.38006384519922 4.913054890930653, 52.35631327204287 4.913054890930653, 52.35631327204287 4.881156384944916)'))
```

However it seems to return all the rows in the table, I have no idea what is going wrong here. 
Maybe someone could point me in the right direction.

Edit:

For example it returns this row:

```
# AREAGEOMETRY_ID, AreaManagerId, AreaId, EndDateArea, StartDateArea, AreaGeometryTxt
493, 299, 8721, 0000-00-00 00:00:00, 0000-00-00 00:00:00, POLYGON ((6.071624141 51.927465383, 6.071167939 51.927755315, 6.073816653 51.928513734, 6.07434586 51.928376592, 6.072239751 51.927748706, 6.072269225 51.927414931, 6.071624141 51.927465383))
```

Which it shouldn't.

Edit2: 
Some possible viewports and their results:

Viewport 1:

```
LatLngBounds{southwest=lat/lng: (52.367693923958065,6.981273405253887), northeast=lat/lng: (52.3812037840295,6.99942022562027)}
```

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM AREAGEOMETRY WHERE ST_CONTAINS(GeomFromText('LINESTRING(52.367693923958065 6.981273405253887, 52.3812037840295 6.981273405253887, 52.3812037840295 6.99942022562027, 52.367693923958065 6.99942022562027, 52.367693923958065 6.981273405253887)'), GeomFromText(AreaGeometryTxt));
```

Expected Result: 0 rows returned

Actual Result: 0 rows returned

Viewport 2:

```
LatLngBounds{southwest=lat/lng: (52.20765248996001,6.881230026483536), northeast=lat/lng: (52.23028692988024,6.911527253687382)}
```

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM AREAGEOMETRY WHERE ST_CONTAINS(GeomFromText('LINESTRING(52.20765248996001 6.881230026483536, 52.23028692988024 6.881230026483536, 52.23028692988024 6.911527253687382, 52.20765248996001 6.911527253687382, 52.20765248996001 6.881230026483536)'), GeomFromText(AreaGeometryTxt));
```

Expected Result: About 25 rows returned

Actual Result: 0 rows returned

Another query same viewport:

```
SELECT * FROM AREAGEOMETRY WHERE ST_Overlaps(GeomFromText('LINESTRING(52.20765248996001 6.881230026483536, 52.23028692988024 6.881230026483536, 52.23028692988024 6.911527253687382, 52.20765248996001 6.911527253687382, 52.20765248996001 6.881230026483536)'), GeomFromText(AreaGeometryTxt));
```

Expected Result: About 25 rows returned

Actual Result: 1000 rows returned (limited by MySQL Workbench)

**Edit 3:**
The following query returns exactly what I want:

```
SELECT * FROM AREAGEOMETRY WHERE ST_Intersects(GeomFromText('Polygon((6.881230026483536 52.20765248996001, 6.881230026483536 52.23028692988024, 6.911527253687382 52.20765248996001, 6.881230026483536 52.20765248996001))'), GeomFromText(AreaGeometryTxt));
```

Seems like I mixed up Lat/Lng and had the parameters in the wrong order.

Comment: Have you tried `MBRContains()` in place of `ST_Overlaps()`?

Comment: @OllieJones. If the geometry is a rectangle, MBRContains and Contains will return the same thing, although you are right to point out that Overlaps is probably the wrong operator to be using.

Comment: I've tried MBRContains() and it returns 0 rows.

Comment: The folks at [Geographic Information Systems Stack Exchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/ "Geographic Information Systems Stack Exchange") are very good on geospatial queries, and might have better answers.

Answer (score 2):

You should use Contains or Intersects, depending on whether you want objects on the border to be included, or whether you want full containment. 
However, your main issue, is that you have the geometries the wrong way round, if you look at the [Contains documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/spatial-relation-functions-mbr.html#function_contains) you will see it is Contains(g1, g2) returns 1 if g1 contains g2, so you will want to put your bounding box first.

```
SELECT * FROM AREAGEOMETRY WHERE ST_CONTAINS(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(52.35631327204287 4.881156384944916, 52.38006384519922 4.881156384944916, 52.38006384519922 4.913054890930653, 52.35631327204287 4.913054890930653, 52.35631327204287 4.881156384944916)'), ST_GeomFromText(AreaGeometryTxt));
```

You might also want to consider storing AreaGeometryTxt as a geometry, rather than text, as this will give you two advantages:

1. You can then put a [spatial index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/creating-spatial-indexes.html) on it, which will lead to much faster query times as table size grows.
2. You will avoid the overhead of the GeomFromText conversion on each query, which in conjunction with point 1, will prevent doing a full table scan each time.

**EDIT:** I ran the following query, using the row you say should not be returned, and your original lat/lon bounding box:

```
select ST_Overlaps(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON ((6.071624141 51.927465383, 6.071167939 51.927755315, 6.073816653 51.928513734, 6.07434586 51.928376592, 6.072239751 51.927748706, 6.072269225 51.927414931, 6.071624141 51.927465383))'),
                ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON ((4.881156384944916 52.35631327204287, 4.881156384944916 52.38006384519922, 4.913054890930653 52.38006384519922, 4.913054890930653 52.35631327204287, 4.881156384944916 52.35631327204287))'));
```

This query returned 0 (false) for `overlaps`, `intersects` and `contains` as it should.

Comment: Hi John, Thank you for the information about the Spatial Indexes, I am going to implement them. However your query still gives me way more rows in return than I want. It should return about 50 rows, however it returns all the rows in the table.

Comment: If you could add a couple of geometries to your question that you expect to be outside, it would help with diagnosis.

Comment: Also, I made a mistake and have edited my query. Should be contains -- not sure if it will make a difference. If not, please add some geometries to test against

Comment: I have added a row, which it should not return, is that what you meant? I see that you have changed your query, please give me a minute to test it.

Comment: I have added some more examples.

Comment: Hi Rik, I ran a query against one of the rows you say should not be returned and your example bounding box, and it returns false for overlaps, contains, and intersects, as it should. I am at a bit of a loss.

Comment: Also, I notice that some of your example coordinates have lat/lon and others are in the order lon/lat, though this would make them even less likely to intersect, it is a potential source of confusion, which means you could be in Germany, Somalia or French Guyana, depending on which way you interpret the 6 and 52.

Comment: Hi John, All of the given coordinates are places in the Netherlands. I still haven't really found a good query to select the right information, maybe my approach is wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59967/discussion-between-rik-and-john-barca).

Comment: Hi Rik, the approach of using where Intersects/Contains(area_of_interest, geometries) is completely standard and you have seen my edit. I am very happy to continue this in chat, but I have just driven from Italy to Spain and am really sick, so tomorrow some time.

Comment: I have just grabbed the latest MySQL binaries, so we are on the same page, so to speak.